# How do I upload a file(<16MB, word, pdf) to MongoDb using nextjs? I do not wish to use GridFS because of the complexity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, web-applications, next.js

I am fairly new to nextJS and I created a simple web where an employer can post a job listing  and is stored in mongodb. the job listing is saved in a collection and one of the fields is called 'joblistingattachment' where it should store a pdf or word file. I have added validations in client side to restrict the size of the file to a max of 2MB. Therefore I do not wish to use GridFS but a simple alternative. Can anyone suggest me an idea and mention the steps and resources needed briefly?

thank you in advance

Comment: In addition to GridFS, you can also store data within a MongoDB document, as binary data (of type binData). The document size limit of 16 MB applies.

Answer (score 1):

Pdfs `should not be uploaded` to your MongoDB database. Your pdfs should be uploaded to some hosting such as [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/), for example, and then you should save generated link.

How it should work:

1. You save your pdf/image to your hosting (via NodeJS)
2. As feedback you should have a link to your file/pdf.
3. You save a link in MongoDB.

A lot of hostings propose different approaches of public/private access to the links, reduced upload time/quality, etc.

Important: imagine you have to upload a collection of 15MB(you managed to add your pdf as binary), you will have a [Vercel error](https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-bypass-vercel-5mb-body-size-limit-serverless-functions) (error code 413).

Comment: File sizes are <= 2mb. Vercel has a maximum of 5mb which is way above my maximum. I prefer to use MongoDB by converting the files to Bson or any easier way. The problem is I looked everywhere for a clear explanation but couldn't find one. Thanks

Comment: So, how will you get the collection after, for example, 100 records?

Comment: From your question, I'm guessing there is no way? Is there?

Comment: There is always a solution you can find, for example, if you need to get a collection with 100 elements (20mb total size), you can donwload your data partly, for example with parts of 20-30 elements for each mongodb call, but it makes more work to do. Also it reduces the performance of your web pages.

Comment: Thank you Illia. Now I will have to go with what you mentioned before. Do you have any online documentation on it? I appreciate your help

Comment: Which hosting for image/pdf did you choose?

Comment: I finally decide to use S3 to store my pdf and word documents.